# android app speed/framerate?

Tags: android, performance, sprite, frame-rate

I created an app for android. I'm using canvas and making more and more "Sprites" from my Sprite class. when i start the app and there is only one sprite the game runs super fast. I made the class to create more sprites every time the timer i set up gets to 25 (so there would be an even space between each sprite). but when each of the sprites appear and it get to the max that i have made (5) it gets slower. So, my question is, How can set a custom framerate/speed to my app. Is it even possible? and if it does can you please write the easiest way? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed? This is a bit of a loaded question. Are you using a SurfaceView then overriding the draw function? Also how are you loading images?

Comment: I am using a surface view and a thread to handle the drawing. I'm loading bitmaps and using rects to create a sprite animation. all the other stuff happens between the lockcanvas and the postcanvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a good article](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) on how to set up a game loop. That will help you control the framerate of your app (make it consistent). Also, note how you doesn't wait a constant amount after drawing. Instead, you wait a constant amount of time between frames.

Comment: i have one problem, when i type 'const int ...' it says that i cant use const and draw a red line under it.. any ideas?

Comment: I don't get it, it wont work with most of the things in the article.. -_- i cant use any of them... any ideas? i'm not even sure if its for android... when i type in the code, i can't use const, DWORD, or GetTickCount();

Comment: The article isn't specific to Android. It's using C++ for the code. Java uses `final` instead of `const` (although the meaning is slightly different). Use `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` instead of `GetTickCount()`.